# Why does `gem install` succeed but `bundle install` fails?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to install gtk3, but bundle install chokes while installing atk. Most of the responses seem to resolve around mismatched versions in the lock file. Removing the lock file doesn't help, neither does installing the matching version of bundle.

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/....
Resolving dependencies...
Using bundler 2.4.6
Fetching native-package-installer 1.1.5
Fetching pkg-config 1.5.1
Installing pkg-config 1.5.1
Installing native-package-installer 1.1.5
Fetching glib2 3.5.1
Installing glib2 3.5.1 with native extensions
Fetching atk 3.5.1
Installing atk 3.5.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/sproctor/code/lich-5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/atk-3.5.1/dependency-check
rake RUBYARCHDIR\=/home/sproctor/code/lich-5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/atk-3.5.1
RUBYLIBDIR\=/home/sproctor/code/lich-5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/atk-3.5.1
/home/sproctor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:263:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem
rake (>= 0.a) with executable rake (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /home/sproctor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:282:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    from /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/sproctor/code/lich-5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/atk-3.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to
/home/sproctor/code/lich-5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/atk-3.5.1/gem_make.out

  /home/sproctor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:102:in `run'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/rake_builder.rb:28:in `build'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:170:in `build_extension'
/home/sproctor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:204:in `block in
build_extensions'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:201:in `each'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:201:in `build_extensions'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/installer.rb:843:in `build_extensions'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in `build_extensions'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in `install'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
/home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
/home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:155:in
`do_install'
/home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:146:in `block in
worker_pool'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
/home/sproctor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in
create_threads'

An error occurred while installing atk (3.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  atk
```

However, installing via gem works fine.

```
gem install atk -v 3.5.1
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed atk-3.5.1
Parsing documentation for atk-3.5.1
Done installing documentation for atk after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Comment: Possibly `bundler` uses a different `ruby` with no `rake` installed. Perhaps you also need to have your PATH variable updated. Unfortunately it's been a while since I used `rvm` and now prefer `rbenv`.

Comment: What about the content of the log file `/home/sproctor/code/lich-5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/atk-3.5.1/gem_make.out
` ?

Comment: It seems to be using the correct version of ruby. They're both using 2.7.7. I don't think it's rvm related. It fails in github actions that aren't using rvm: https://github.com/sproctor/lich-5/actions/runs/4093660710/jobs/7059257867#step:3:97

Comment: /home/sproctor/code/lich-5/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/atk-3.5.1/gem_make.out is just lines 14-24 from the output pasted above

Comment: I'm having a suspicion. There are two versions of rake installed: `.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.7/bin/rake` and `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.7/bin/rake`. The only difference is #! line. the first one is the correct version of ruby, the second one is: #!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great answer, so if someone has a more in depth explanation, please feel free to give a better answer.

`gem install gtk3` and `bundle install` use a different copy of `rake`.

The only difference between the two is the shebang line. The version from bundler is `#!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks` while the other version points to a specific version of ruby.

I'm not sure why this fails for the bundler version.

An easy workaround mentioned here: https://github.com/postmodern/digest-crc/issues/18#issuecomment-652889761 is to add `gem "rake"` to your `Gemfile`.